# Causality and Stability of a discrete-time LTI system which has ROC = {z : 4/3 < |z| < 2}

Tags: transfer-function

The transfer function H(z) of a discrete-time LTI system has ROC={z ∈ C : 4/3 <|z|< 2}. The system is...

a) Causal and stable

b) Stable but non-causal

c) Unstable but causal

d) Neither causal nor stable

My teacher uploaded the answer and the option he marked as correct was d)Neither causal nor stable. I get why it is not causal **but why is it unstable?**

Comment: Could you explain in your question why you think that the system is stable?

Comment: I don't know if I'm correct, but I thought that If the ROC included the region outside the unit circle the system was stable

Comment: The region outside the unit circle is $|z|>1$. Does the given ROC include that region?

Comment: ||>4/3 which is larger than 1, so then I guess it includes that region or not? Honestly, I'm not sure, I don't know I'm a first year student I don't know anything.